# Best way to write a java class to 'optionally' override a method which may not exist in the associated interface at runtime

Tags: java

I'm looking to write an abstract class which extends `javax.sql.DataSource` and may be used from either a Java 1.8 JVM (i.e. JDBC 4.2), or a Java 1.9+ JVM (i.e. JDBC 4.3)

JDBC 4.3 introduced the `createConnectionBuilder​()` method, which returns an instance of `java.sql.ConnectionBuilder` (which is also new for Java 1.9).

I know (correct me if I'm wrong) that I could simply opt to not override this method, and since it has a default implementation, if it's called in a Java 1.9+ JVM that default implementation would get used rather than causing any error.

But if I wish to override it in case it does get called, how could I do that? The dilemma seems to be that if I want it to be useable in a Java 1.8 JVM, I should build it with a Java 1.8 JDK, but in that case it would fail to resolve the new type (not to mention complain about any `@Override` I added [I think I can simply omit that, but annoying]). A possible option might be to give the compiler a definition of the JDBC 4.3 version of the interfaces in question during compilation (I'm not exactly sure how to do that, but I think we've done that before in my company for a similar issue), but the concern that comes to mind is, is the class guaranteed to load if one of its methods returns a type that can't be resolved? (In that case it'll never get called, I'm just worried that the JVM might try to resolve the return type and fail to load it)

edit: I'll try to clarify what I'm trying to accomplish.

This class is meant to be a shim which, at runtime, depending on the Java version supported by the JVM, forwards methods called on it to either a JDBC 4.2, or 4.3 implementation of `DataSource` (former being built using `-release 8` & latter with `-release 9` [& might override `createConnectionBuilder​()`]. Since we need this class to load in either JVM, it needs to be built with `-release 8` (or `-target 1.8`, but this can be problematic, see [JEP 247](https://openjdk.org/jeps/247)). I don't think building it using `-release 8` is possible, since `java.sql.ConnectionBuilder` isn't part of Java 8.

Comment: The simplest solution is not to call the `createConnectionBuilder​()` method at all.  If you must have the method, write the method using Java 1.8 compilable code.

Comment: But can that be done if the return type of the method only exists in Java 1.9+?

Comment: Create the return type too.